# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found in /home/******/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 553

Tags: php, magento, helper, megamenu

Im trying to install mega menu in magento and am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found in /home/******/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 553

Can anyone help? Can you please explain as simply as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i hope you are installing a third party module. :)

The problem is app/Mage.php could not find the helper file in Magenotification module as define in etc/config.xml

1. go to app/code/community or app/code/local
2. go to Magenotification module's Helper directory
3. make sure you have a helper file in Helper/Data.php, if not create one.

The helper should contain a proper class like this

Namesapace_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}

Comment: it has class Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{ code here } in there already. The module im trying to add is Mega Menu. Do I need to reference mega menu here or something?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and fixed it by running:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

but you should have permisions 777 at includes folder to recreate src